# Eclipse IDE suddenly gone after installation?

Tags: eclipse, windows-10

I tried installing the [Eclipse IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), installation is successful. After installation, it runs and I successfully run a simple Hello World program.

I closed the IDE, and later I tried to open it but I couldn't find the application either on my startup menu and desktop. I tried to open my Control Panel but I couldn't find it there too.

I reinstall the IDE and the same thing happened. Am I missing something here? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Did you use the Eclipse Installer or downloaded a ZIP file? What's in ´%USERPROFILE%\eclipse` directory?

Comment: I downloaded the installer, not the zip file.

Comment: In the Eclipse Installer, which Eclipse IDE package did you choose? What was in the _Installation Folder_ field and was _create start menu entry_ and _create desktop shortcut_ checked?